# `stack build` failed, it uses a strange version of bytestring

Tags: haskell

I've used the following commands to set up ghc and stack:

```
$ ghcup set ghc 9.4.2
$ stack config set system-ghc true
```

then

```
$ which ghc
~/.ghcup/bin/ghc
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.4.2
```

and in `~/.stack/pantry/global-hints-cache.yaml`

```
ghc-9.4.2:
  Cabal: 3.8.1.0
  Cabal-syntax: 3.8.1.0
  Win32: 2.12.0.0
  array: 0.5.4.0
  base: 4.17.0.0
  binary: 0.8.9.1
  bytestring: 0.11.3.1
  containers: 0.6.6
  deepseq: 1.4.8.0
  directory: 1.3.7.1
  exceptions: 0.10.5
  filepath: 1.4.2.2
  ghc: 9.4.2
  ghc-bignum: '1.3'
  ghc-boot: 9.4.2
  ghc-boot-th: 9.4.2
  ghc-compact: 0.1.0.0
  ghc-heap: 9.4.2
  ghc-prim: 0.9.0
  ghci: 9.4.2
  haskeline: 0.8.2
  hpc: 0.6.1.0
  integer-gmp: '1.1'
  libiserv: 9.4.2
  mtl: 2.2.2
  parsec: 3.1.15.0
  pretty: 1.1.3.6
  process: 1.6.15.0
  rts: 1.0.2
  stm: 2.5.1.0
  system-cxx-std-lib: '1.0'
  template-haskell: 2.19.0.0
  terminfo: 0.4.1.5
  text: 2.0.1
  time: 1.12.2
  transformers: 0.5.6.2
  unix: 2.7.3
  xhtml: 3000.2.2.1
```

in project `package.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- vector
- aeson
- bytestring >= 0.11.3.1
- containers
- MissingH
```

but

```
$ stack build

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for cis194s15-0.1.0.0:
    bytestring-0.10.12.1 from stack configuration does not match >=0.11.3.1  (latest matching version is 0.11.3.1)
needed since cis194s15 is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' in ~/.stack/config.yaml to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in ~/gitee.com/cis194-15/stack.yaml:

- bytestring-0.11.3.1@sha256:0cc97b237df9a34d12de37973ad306391e24b0c262387c4d846bb8d1d65699dd,7339

Plan construction failed.


$ stack --version|grep bytestring                                                                                                                                                                                       
- base16-bytestring-1.0.1.0
- base64-bytestring-1.2.0.1
- bytestring-0.10.12.0
```

The question is: I cannot find where I specified the version 0.10.12.1 for `bytestring`, only `>= 0.11.3.1` in `package.yaml` and so in the `.cabal` file.

BTW, neither of the `different approaches` stack gives are acceptable for me.

Comment: Are you using an unofficial mirror with stack like you were with cabal?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Ok. I've found the local project's `stack.yaml` still  uses the unofficial mirror. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: To set `stack` configuration I think it is neccesary to pass the `global` parameter: `stack config set install-ghc --global false` and `stack config set system-ghc --global true`.

Comment: This seems interesting, are you moving on from university projects, using its templates?

Comment: It seems stack does not work with ghc-9.4.2 and cabal3.8.1.0. I've downgraded to ghc8.

Comment: `stack` uses [stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) as a package repository. Latest stable version of `ghc` is 9.0.2